# Accidentally deleted the system `uuidd` user and group -- which package to reinstall?

Tags: package-management, system, uuid

I accidentally deleted the system user `uuidd` and their group from my system.

I want to reinstall the package they belong to, but when I look for the manual of `uuidd` on the net, it references the `util-linux` package. A reinstall of this package with `sudo apt --reinstall install util-linux` does not bring this user back.

How can I find out which package to reinstall and repair the system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least on my (22.04) system, the user and group appear to get created by the postinst script of the [uuid-runtime package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/uuid-runtime)

```
$ head -n 12 /var/lib/dpkg/info/uuid-runtime.postinst
#!/bin/sh
set -e

# add uuidd user/group if needed.
if ! getent group uuidd >/dev/null; then
        addgroup --system uuidd
fi
if ! getent passwd uuidd >/dev/null; then
        adduser --system --ingroup uuidd \
                --home /run/uuidd --no-create-home \
                uuidd
fi
```